# Skobbler material design

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm embedding customPOIs into my app and would like to know (and see) what are the available material design icons (for accommodation, transportation, etc.) is there any way to do this - like a website or file within the package?
TIA

Comment: As in [this](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) and [this](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons)? A quick Google search should bring these up right at the top of your results list.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I didn't mean Google material design, which I am aware of, I meant the Skobbler specific material design. For example, the icon used to display an accommodation POI (defined by SKCategories.SKPOICategory.SKPOI_CATEGORY_GUEST_HOUSE). I was wondering if there is an accessible list of these icons and their respective SKPOICategorys

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have such a resource available for the moment